Doubt on proof of all triangles being isosceles
We all know the proof of all triangles being isoceles.  If not refer https://jdh.hamkins.org/all-triangles-are-isosceles/. In this proof the flaw is, the perpendiculars drawn from the point Q can lie outside the triangle. But does that mean triangles having all perpendiculars drawn from the point Q inside the triangle are isosceles ? 
I also have a guess on the answer i.e, no triangle other than equilateral and isoceles can have perpendiculars drawn from the point Q being inside the triangle. But still, even for this guess I don't have proof. If my guess is right please consider giving the proof too. 
Thanks to everyone who tried to solve it in advance

I don't know the proof, and your link is broken.

Sorry for the inconvenience please check it now

Thanks, seems to work now

$Q$ is not in general the incenter of the triangle.

@eyeballfrog Sorry I changed it now to be point Q

Q is the incentre, but P is not the midpoint of BC. QP is the inradius, not the perpendicular bisector of BC.

@Gwen Q is not the incenter. Q is the intersection of the angle bisector and the perpendicular bisector of the opposite side.

Yes Q is not the incentre

@CalvinLin True

Unless I'm mistaken, if $AC \ne AB$, then $Q$ is always outside the triangle.

@eyeballfrog yeah that's my guess too but I need the proof for that.

In the comments of your link, someone posted a Geogebra figure which you can play with and get more insight. What you can notice is that 1/ Q is always outside the triangle, 2/ R and S are such that one is within the triangle and one is outside of the triangle, 3/ For an isosceles triangle, where $Q$ is defined by a limiting process, then $R, S$ coincide with $A, B$.  With these observations, it should be clearer what is happening.

I for one choose to welcome our ultrametric universe and reject these silly Archimedian notions!

@CalvinLin I saw it but why can't the point Q never lie inside a triangle what is the reason and why is it so...The reason is what I am looking for

@RishwanthSV It's just a joke---there exists mathematical spaces (called ultrametric spaces) in which it's genuinely true that every triangle is isosceles. Euclidean space, in which you are drawing your triangles, is not one of them.

Hints towards understanding the setup, esp the 3 points I raised in my comment. If you're stuck, explain what you've tried.

Show that $Q$ lies on the circumcircle of $ABC$, hence is always outside the triangle.
Show that $AR = AS = \frac{ AB+AC}{2}$.
Show that $BR = CS = \frac{ |AC - AB| } {2}$.
Hence, for a non-isosceles triangle, one of R, S is inside AB, AC, and the other is outside.

Hence, conclude that if both perpendiculars drawn from the point Q are "inside", then the triangle must be isosceles.


This explains how the proof "works". What is actually happening is that we need to consider these as directed line segments, where $AR+RB = AB, AS + SC = AC$.
Bonus: For an isosceles triangle, where $Q$ is defined in a limiting process, shown that $R = A, S = B$.

So the perpendiculars never end up truly inside, but just touching.




Thanks I understood it now...I would have understood it already in the comments but I mistook 1/ Q stuff as 1÷Q so I am sorry that you had to put up an answer.
